# Prove that the inductively defined sequence is monotone and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence $x(n)$ is defined as follows -

$x(1) > 1$

$x(n+1) = 2 - \frac{1}{x(n)}$

Show that the inductively defined sequence is monotone and bounded.

It was pretty easy to show it is bounded above by $2$ and bounded below by $1$. 
But I am not able to find any relation event b/w $x(n+1)$ and $x(n)$.

I do believe(MAYBE) that there is no fixed relation b/w $x(1)$ and $x(2)$ though, since x(1) is arbitrary. I think we'd be looking for a relation for $n>1$.

Also, I believe it'll be a decreasing sequence since, with the m-tail property, we can find that the sequence converges to $1$.

Comment: The above notation is impossible to understand. What is $1 x(n + 1)$? What does $[\cdot]$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0< (x_n-1)^2$

$0 < x_n^2 - 2x_n + 1$

$2x_n-1 < x_n^2$

$2 - \frac{1}{x_n} < x_n$

$x_{n+1}  < x_n$